# Stream frame from video to pipeline and publish it to HTTP mjpeg via ffmpeg

Tags: windows, opencv, ffmpeg, html5-video, pipeline

Let's say I have very simple program which has been written in C++ with usage of OpenCV 3.4  under Windows 10.

```
VideoCapture cap("test.avi");
Mat frame; 
while(true){
    if (!cap.read(frame))  
    { 
        break;
    }
    // SEND FRAME TO PIPE
}
```

It's just simple example of reading frame by frame avi video, but in the end it's going to be server-side application which produces modified stream from few ip cameras. I want to use html5 video tag to display output directly on website, but it's quite hard to find useful information related with that topic ( for Windows ). If I understand it correctly I need to define pipeline and send there MJPEG stream, with help of FFMPEG, where FFMPEG will create local HTTP server on specific port. Anyone ever challenged similar task under Windows? I guess that 80% of task is related with proper usage of ffmpeg command line tool, one of my priorities is minimal modification of application.

So to make long story short, I have application which I can call directly from command line :

```
stream_producer.exe CAMERA_1
```

and I want to be able to see MJPEG stream under :

```
http://localhost:1234
```

which can be displayed on local website in intranet.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I tired to use ffmpeg and few other workarounds, but the easiest way to do it was :

http://answers.opencv.org/question/6976/display-iplimage-in-webbrowsers/

Final version should have :

```
_write(client, (char*)"HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n", 0);
        _write(client, (char*)"Server: Mozarella/2.2\r\n"
            "Accept-Range: bytes\r\n"
            "Connection: close\r\n"
            "Max-Age: 0\r\n"
            "Expires: 0\r\n"
            "Cache-Control: no-cache, private\r\n"
            "Pragma: no-cache\r\n"
            "Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=mjpegstream\r\n"
            "\r\n", 0);
```

Thanks ;-)